# NumPy: Erroneous result when modifying array using itself

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, undefined-behavior

```
import numpy as np
bc = np.arange(10) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

# regular way using NumPy function
np.diff(bc) # array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

# something similar with array subtraction:
bc[1:] - bc[:-1] # array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

# but this does the wrong thing:
bc[1:] -= bc[:-1] # array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5])
```

As a C and C++ programmer I can understand why this happens (it's memcpy() instead of memmove() all over again), but it seems like end users of Python and NumPy might not expect this.  And I failed to find any documentation saying this wouldn't work.

The question is: is there a bug in NumPy here (probably not), or is there some NumPy documentation explaining what the rules are in situations like this, or is that missing from the documentation?

Secondly, I would like to figure out a safe, working solution which is quasi-optimal in space and time.  That is, it should not allocate memory beyond a constant amount, and it should not be a silly pure-Python "for" loop.  :)  Those are the goals one might hope to achieve with the in-place modification which clearly doesn't work.

I'm using NumPy 1.8.0.

Comment: Internally `diff` uses that same slice difference.  Slices don't use any extra memory.  The only added memory use is for the output.  Since the output has a different size than the input, I don't see the need for an inplace difference (especially if the diff step is larger than 1).

Comment: `np.subtract(bc[1:],bc[:-1],out=bc[:-1])` produces `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9]` - the desired difference, except that the unchanged term is at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find some discussion after posting this question.  The important term to search for is "slice".  It's here: http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/Strange-behavior-in-setting-masked-array-values-in-Numpy-1-1-0-td11999.html

Partway down the page there is discussion about trying to detect and warn about this sort of thing, but it sounds like a lost cause.  So I set about finding another in-place method to do what I wanted.  Here it is!

```
bc[-1:0:-1] -= bc[-2::-1]
```

Credit to [@fredtantini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3336968/fredtantini) for explicitly writing out the pure-Python "for" loop which NumPy effectively does.  That got me thinking about how to fix it in pure Python (iterate backward!), which led to the above solution.

Comment: Seriously, before you do that kind of dangerous trick... the non-inplace version which returns a new array is just as fast probably, since allocating an array is not that bad and it is in a better strided manner.

Comment: I don't think this method is dangerous.  Do you?  If so, what might go wrong?  Anyway, allocating a new array is the usual path of least resistance, but if the array is many gigabytes in size, it won't really work.  :)

Comment: This might be dangerous if numpy developers change the way an array is iterated.  For example, most `memcpy` implementations "copy forward" but it's not required of them that they do.  Does the numpy spec guarantee iteration order?

Comment: I think things are dangerous if you cannot generalize them to higher dimensions for example (and I am pretty sure you cannot do that here). This one may be safe, but I don't like this kind of advice too much, because I feel it is "if you know what you are doing" type of advice.

Answer (score 1):

Im posting here again to correct my answer.
perhaps try:

```
bc-=np.roll( bc , 1 )

#array([-9,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1])
#this arrays length is 10

#and then for an array with length 9
bc=bc[ 1 : ]  

#array([1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1])
```

sorry miss-understood the question before,

the reason for the result:

```
'array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5])'
```

is

that this action is actually syntaxed as the deduction of

```
let (say...) a=array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
updated a <- will be formed as [0, 1-0=1,2-1=1,3-1=2,4-2=2,5-2=3,6-3=3,7-3=4,8-4=4,9-4=5]
```

I think what you really want is above

tnx EdChum

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's a bug:
Doing `bc[1:] -= bc[:-1]` you are modifying the list while doing the operations.

The process is like

```
for i in range(1,len(bc)):
    bc[i] = bc[i] - bc[i-1]
```

So the next step `bc[i-1]` is modified:

```
"i"      1
bc[1:]:  1,2,3,4,5,…
bc[:-1]: 0,1,2,3,4,5,… 
bc[1]= 1 - 0 = 1
new bc: 0,1,2,3,4,5,…

"i"        2
bc[1:]:  1,2,3,4,5,…
bc[:-1]: 0,1,2,3,4,5,… 
bc[2]= 2 - 1 = 1
new bc: 0,1,1,3,4,5,…


"i"          3
bc[1:]:  1,1,3,4,5,…
bc[:-1]: 0,1,1,3,4,5,… 
bc[1]= 3 - 1 = 2
new bc: 0,1,1,2,4,5,…


"i"            4
bc[1:]:  1,1,2,4,5,…
bc[:-1]: 0,1,1,2,4,5,… 
bc[1]= 4 - 2 = 2
new bc: 0,1,1,2,2,5,…
```

And so on so forth.

For the rest of the question, I can't answer.

Comment: Yes I understand this.  My question is stated at the bottom of my post...namely whether it is an outright bug, or is documented somewhere, and if it is not a bug, if there is some safe formulation of the same thing which is quasi-optimal in space and time.